# Elliptic curve in terms of complex geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

An elliptic curve over complex numbers is a complex manifold given by an equation on $(x,y)$-plane

$$y^2=x^3+ax+b$$

And I have a question - since this is a complex manifold, what local complex coordinates can I choose and what will happen on the overlap of charts? Do such coordinates exist for any $a$ and $b$? Or is there a subset of parameters for which the overlap functions are singular?

Comment: Hint: implicit function theorem

Comment: @ronno I don't quite understand how this theorem will help me choose comlpex coordinates charts

Comment: Can you show that the conic given by solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a complex manifold? That is, find local coordinates and decide what happens on the overlap of charts?

Comment: An alternative approach is to show a suitable Weierstrass $\wp$ function and its derivative parametrize the cubic. Ahlfors' _Complex Analysis_ has a good account, if memory serves.

Comment: @ronno Do u mean that x and y are complex numbers?  Because I’m not sure that a 1-dimensional manifold could be a complex manifold.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, I know this approach, thank you. But I would like to understand from the complex geometry side - that I can get restrictions on $a$ and $b$ from the transition functions

Comment: Parametrizing by the Weierstrass $\wp$ function _is_ the complex geometry side. :) A global parametrization restricted to an "injective open set" is (the inverse of) a holomorphic coordinate system. <> If you go the implicit function theorem route, yes $x$ and $y$ are complex (and there are points at infinity that need to be restored if you want the whole compact curve). Here, incidentally, you can explicitly solve for $x$, or solve for $y$, and the resulting neighborhoods cover for generic $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yes, *of course* $x$ and $y$ are complex. And the elliptic curve is *usually* considered to be the closure of this curve in $\Bbb P^2_{\Bbb C}$.

Comment: @ronno I think I was able to show that a conic is a complex manifold. Using implicit function theorem we have two sets $U_x=(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$ and $U_x=(y,\sqrt{1-y^2})$ and $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ and we have two homeomorphisms between $U_x (U_y)$ and an open neighbourhood $W$ of $0\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi_y(x,y)=y-y_0$ is a local coordinate at all points besides $(0,\pm 1)$ and $\phi_x(x,y)=x-x_0$ at all ponts  besides $(\pm 1, 0)$.Since $x,y$ are complex we have two complex charts. On the overlap of charts we have transition fucntion $f(z)=\sqrt{1-(z-y_0)^2}$.We have a complex atlas.

Comment: Okay, now what about your original question?

Comment: @ronno Here I have difficulties, because in one of the charts I need to solve this equation for $x$, i.e. $x=f(y)$

Comment: The theorem tells you that locally there is a solution, without writing it down explicitly.